# How center SWF's in AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I making something that will load an SWF from another site. The script is in AS2 and I would like to know how to center it. http://cpcheatsdojo.info/SWFViewer/FD.swf?id=1 Thats how it looks like now, how can I make it center.
The code is:

```
var id = 1;
createEmptyMovieClip("i",100);
i.loadMovie("http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/v2/content/global/furniture/icons/" + id + ".swf");
```

So what can i add to it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the X and Y values to the position you need (you can calculate this position by figuring out the stage width and height and dividing by 2 along with the width and height of the swf.)

```
i._x = 50; //change these numbers
i._y = 50; //change these numbers
```